# task manager for Internet usage, I need to block a software accessing a website/web server

Tags: internet, firewall, monitoring

I have a software that accesses a website, I want to monitor what website is it accessing and block that website. Is there a software similar to "windows task manager" that allows you to monitor software that accesses a website? I want to know what website/server is it accessing so I could then block it. And Is there an alternative way to block aside from "host" file?

Thanks!

FYI: running on Win7

Answer (score 0):

The built-in firewall itself will handle this.

Go to Control Panel > Windows Firewall. Choose Advanced settings.

Select Outbound Rules. From the Action menu, choose New Rule.

Follow the prompts to create a rule specific to the problem program.

If you really want to know exactly what data is being sent where, use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Windows Firewall can block connections to just the offending IP address, perhaps leaving the application with limited internet access to perform other more desirable functions. (Note that this is a terrible idea as software is hardly immutable).

As an aside, unless this is a one-of-a-kind application that you can't live without, consider uninstalling it. Any code exhibiting this kind of unwanted behavior probably doesn't belong on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Use this free Outbound firewall utility, it integrates into the W7 firewall, makes it easier to block specific programs from reaching the internet.

http://www.sphinx-soft.com/Vista/order.html

.